# Is it possible for a lightsaber to be made in a Y shape?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Suppose you made a lightsaber shaped like a Y, and in a battle fought with the one going straight. If you activated the other blade when you and your foe crossed blades, it would go right through them before they could block it, right? Is this possible?

Comment: _is this possible?_ As far as I know, no one on this site can actually make a lightsaber.

Comment: Not off-topic, just not a quality question.

Comment: The question just made me laugh..

Comment: Obligatory: http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/57512300.jpg

Comment: Of course, it might also go right through one of your legs as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In fact, something very similar exists in Legends: called the [crossguard lightsaber or forked lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Crossguard_lightsaber). The only one described was used by the Jedi Master [Roblio Darté](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Roblio_Dart%C3%A9) during (and shortly after) the Clone Wars:

[image: Crossguard saber]

However, I don't believe he ever used it in the way you describe.

Although Roblio's secondary saber blade was only knife-length, in principle there's no reason it couldn't be full-sized; we have evidence of both [variable-length lightsabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dual-phase_lightsaber), and double-bladed sabers with multiple activators.

Comment: I think the OP means two full length blades, not a cross guard.

Comment: @Daft I think you're right, but it demonstrates the principle. Adjusting the length is comparatively easy

Comment: @JasonBaker - I would add that, since double-bladed lightsabers exist (like Darth Maul's, with one full-length blade coming out of each end of the hilt/handle), and since we know that a shortened crossguard blade at an angle to the main blade is possible, it is possible (though not necessarily practical) to have a lightsaber with two full-length blades in a Y formation.  It would, however, be extremely clumsy and unwieldy, and insanely dangerous to use.